# How to pass string variable to SQL query using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a db query that is looking for a string value in a specific key and should return a count of how many times it finds that specific string in that key field.  One query (Query #1 below) works fine.

I have a second query, against a second db table.  Query #2 below.  The query is the same as in #1, except the db names and variable names were changed.  This query always returns 0.  If, instead of passing the string to search for via variable, I pass it as static text, it works fine.  (Query #3 below)

Query 1 (works):    ($hikername and $nameofthishike are filled via earlier function.  I have confirmed they hold the correct string data.)

```
global $wpdb;
$querystring=$hikername.$nameofthishike;
$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(*) FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE `form_name` = %s AND `field_name` = %s AND `field_value` LIKE %s", 'Hike_Sign_Up_Form','hike_hiker_key','%'.$querystring.'%');
$results=$wpdb->get_var($query);`
```

Query 2 (always returns 0):

```
global $wpdb;
$eventquerystring = $hikername.$nameofthisevent;
$eventqueryresults = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(*) FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE `form_name` = %s AND `field_name` = %s AND `field_value` LIKE %s", 'Event_Sign_Up_Form','hike_hiker_key','%'.$eventquerystring.'%') ;           
$eventresults=$wpdb->get_var($eventqueryresults);`
```

IF I replace the variable $eventquerystring with a text string, say 'SearchForThisKey' (a known value in the db), then the query will work:

```
global $wpdb;
$eventquerystring = $hikername.$nameofthisevent;
$eventqueryresults = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(*) FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE `form_name` = %s AND `field_name` = %s AND `field_value` LIKE %s", 'Event_Sign_Up_Form','hike_hiker_key','SearchForThisKey') ;           
$eventresults=$wpdb->get_var($eventqueryresults);`
```

Comment: You shoud escape % characters. Check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/how-do-you-properly-prepare-a-like-sql-statement) out.

Comment: Thanks for the input 54V4N7, however I don't believe the % characters in the %s sql query placeholders are actually escaped.   I will however check to see if I have any other % that should be escaped.

Comment: This code works:  `$eventresults = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(*) FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE `form_name` = %s AND `field_name` = %s AND `field_value` LIKE %s", 'Event_Sign_Up_Form','hike_hiker_key','SCAMR WordPressAdminTEST HIKE – 15 SEPT 2019')) ; `

Comment: However, replacing the final string parameter with a variable causes the query to return 0 (it doesn't find the item):  `$eventresults = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(*) FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE `form_name` = %s AND `field_name` = %s AND `field_value` LIKE %s", 'Event_Sign_Up_Form','hike_hiker_key',$eventquerystring)) ; `    It clearly has something to do with passing the variable.

Comment: Change Event_Sign_Up_Form to Hike_Sign_Up_Form and $eventquerystring to $querystring and it works just fine.   Can't see any difference between the Event_... and Hike_... db tables however.